# Tensorboard not updating by batch in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard in google colab, it's works fine if i want to track the epochs. However, i want to track the accuracy/loss by batch. I'm trying it using the getting started at documentation [https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but if i change the argument `update_freq` by `update_freq="batch"` it doesn't work. I have tried in my local pc and it works. Any idea of what is happening?

Using tensorboard 2.8.0 and tensorflow 2.8.0

### Code (running in colab)

```py
%load_ext tensorboard
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
!rm -rf ./logs/
```

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def create_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  ])
```

```py
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir = "logs/fit_2/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, update_freq="batch")

model.fit(x=x_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=5, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I've tried to use a integer and it doesn't work either. In my local computer i've no problems.

Comment: Do you have the same versions running on your local machine and in the notebook?

Comment: Then I would suggest defining the same versions in colab as on your machine if its working on your machine

Comment: no, i have 2.6.0. However, i looked to the releases change and nothing mention about the update_freq argument. So i guest that in tensorflow/tensorboar 2.8.0 it should work, isn't it?

Comment: Should be, but it would make sense to set the version of colab to the one you have on your local machine to just make sure that it will work then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change after TensorFlow 2.3 made the batch-level summaries part of the `Model.train_function` rather than something that the TensorBoard callback creates itself. This resulted in a 2x improvement in speed for many small models in `Model.fit`, but it does have the side effect that calling `TensorBoard.on_train_batch_end(my_batch, my_metrics)` in a custom training loop will no longer log batch-level metrics.

This issue was discussed in one of the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43621).

There can be a workaround by creating a custom callback like [LambdaCallback](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/lambda_callback/).

I have modified the last part of your code to explicitly add scalar values of batch_loss and batch_accuracy using `tf.summary.scalar()` to be shown in tensorboard logs.

The code module is as follows:

```
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def batchOutput(batch, logs):
    tf.summary.scalar('batch_loss', data=logs['loss'], step=batch)
    tf.summary.scalar('batch_accuracy', data=logs['accuracy'], step=batch)
    return batch

batchLogCallback = LambdaCallback(on_batch_end=batchOutput)


log_dir = "logs/fit_2/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', update_freq='batch')

model.fit(x=x_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=1, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, batchLogCallback])
```

I tried this in Colab as well it worked.

Comment: Did it work for you? Lemme know @aponce1509

Comment: sorry i couldn't check it until today. It works fine for me too. Thank you very much for the help.